# Validation Rule that depends on success of group of independent rules using Fluent Validation

Tags: fluentvalidation

I'm trying to come up with the right syntax for this scenario:

*RuleA*

*RuleB*

Both above are **independent**
*Rule C* - will run only when BOTH RuleA and RuleB passed the validation.

example:
UserIdExists (RuleA)
OrderIdExists (RuleB)
OrderId belongs to UserId - dependent rule on both above rules success

Code example (which is not working as the OrderBelongsToUser being called even if one of UserIdExists or OrderIdExists failing the validation):

```
RuleFor(request => request).NotNull().DependentRules(() =>
        {
            RuleFor(request => request).CustomAsync(UserIdExists)

            RuleFor(request => request).CustomAsync(OrderIdExists)

        }).CustomAsync(OrderBelongsToUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "UserIdExists" and "OrderIdExists" rules are now only dependent on the request not being null. If you want to only execute the rule "OrderBelongsToUser" if the user and order ID exists you can do the following:

```
RuleFor(request => request)
    .ChildRules(child =>
    {
        child.RuleFor(request => request)
            .CustomAsync(UserIdExists)
            .CustomAsync(OrderIdExists)
    })
    .DependentRules(() =>
    {
        RuleFor(request => request).CustomAsync(OrderBelongsToUser);
    });
```